# Manually defragmenting a Mac? Strange phenomenon with CPU usage

Tags: hard-drive, mac, performance, defragment

[Processes on Mac OSX getting 'stuck' and strange CPU usage](https://superuser.com/questions/441281/processes-on-mac-osx-getting-stuck-and-strange-cpu-usage) describes the same phenomenon, but for writing.  My question concerns reading.

OS X version 10.8.5

I have about 30 million small files on my internal 500GB hard drive, that I will want to back up to several external hard drives.  Because of the number of files, I decided to compress them, move the compressed files around, and decompress them once I'm done.  The compression speed was at 100% CPU usage for the first 80% or so, and then steadily dropped, now to about 3-7% CPU usage, having about 1000 reads / 1MB per second.  Running `top` shows the process as `stuck` most of the time.

The remaining 20% of the files were written when the (spinning) hard drive was almost full (down to 2GB free space when I noticed it); I suspect these files were interspersed throughout the disk, and `stuck` means waiting to read the files from the disk.  I have since deleted certain files, so the disk now has ~50GB free space; however, the performance hasn't improved.

Running `renice -20` or `sudo` makes no difference; also, I read there is no way to defragment a Mac.  I suspect I need to delete the relevant files and write them again when the disk is not as full, in order to be able to match the previous performance.

Is there a way to know where the files are located, so I can verify that this is in fact the source of the problem?  Also, knowing where the files are located can help me figure out where the files started getting interspersed, to know which files to delete and re-write -- and also to verify that the new files are getting written sequentially.

---

**UPDATE**: I am definitely leaning toward the fragmentation explanation.  Going on, the compression CPU usage dropped down to 1-2%.  On the other hand, I tried compressing one of the previous folders, and it completed at the previous speed.  If no better suggestions come up, then I plan just to move the files to another HDD before compressing them, and then decompressing them on my internal HDD.

---

**UPDATE 2**: I noticed an anti-virus script checking the millions of files on the attached USB, running in the background at the `nice 20` level.  I terminated the script, and the compression CPU utilization went back up to the original level.  Apparently even though the compression was running at `nice -20`, it was still getting less priority than the anti-virus script, when it came to system calls.  What's really surprising is, that the anti-virus script was portable, running entirely off of the USB, not even touching the internal HDD -- I am surprised it would have such an effect.  In fact, the situation is not unique to the anti-virus script -- anything that does I/O to a lot of files, such as decompressing the files on the USB drive, causes the same thing to happen.

After stopping the anti-virus, and monitoring the performance, I decided to re-start it to see what happens.  The first file it scans is rather large; even while scanning that file alone, the compression's CPU usage dropped immediately to 0.2%.  Over time, the anti-virus's real memory usage reached 330MB, whereas the compression's real memory usage dropped by about 750MB.  Other than that, no differences are obvious from the `top` command.

So now, it is a replicable phenomenon; if someone offers an explanation, I can test their idea and accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you have already deduced the issue is file fragmentation when it could be something else. Please edit your question to add more details: What model Mac do you have? What version of macOS is being used? How are the hard drives connected? All of this info is needed to help diagnose this issue.

Comment: As @Giacomo1968 states, the issue is likely not fragmentation, but because, "The remaining 20% of the files were written when the (spinning) hard drive was almost full." Make room.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My original post said "I have since deleted certain files, so the disk is no longer close to full" -- in other words, I already made room before posting this question.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Done.  Internal hard drive on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: How big is the drive? How much room was there to start with? How much room have you since freed up? Did you empty the Trash? Are you stopping this process whilst you're trying to erase/defrag/whatever? I presume you realise that defragging is going to make the disk a whole lot more busy that it was in the first place. Why don't you just sleep on it & see how it goes in the morning?

Comment: @Tetsujin Right now, 50GB is free on the 500GB hard drive.  Initially there was only ~2GB free.  I haven't tried erasing / defragging because I'd like to make sure it's making a difference as I'm doing it.

Comment: If you don't stop your compression process, anything else you do will slow you down still further. Are you actually sure your compression will fit the remaining space? Otherwise as it runs it will paint you further & further into a corner. btw, ***the*** Mac defragger from way back when Mountain Lion & SATA II drives were popular was [iDefrag](https://coriolis-systems.com) now given away as freeware/donationware.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, the remaining compressed files should take 3-4GB.  If there are no suggestions as far as how to determine where these files are located on the disk (to verify that the fragmentation is indeed the issue), then I can try iDefrag overnight, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It does seem like an X-Y problem -- but in my case, I am trying to eliminate causes one at a time.  And considering the linked post, I believe it is worthwhile, to check whether fragmentation is indeed the issue here.  Hence this post, asking specifically about the fragmenation issue: to make sure it can be useful to someone in the future facing a fragmentation issue.  I just don't know what other causes there can be...

Comment: @Tetsujin I found a solution to this problem, but I'm not sure why it works.  Feel free to read it, to see if you can explain it as an answer.

Comment: @Alex “What's really surprising is, that the anti-virus script was portable, running entirely from the USB, not even touching the internal HDD…” Why are you running an anti-virus on a USB drive? Was the anti-virus installed on the Mac? Or was it running off of the USB? Unclear.

Comment: No, running off of the USB, and scanning the USB.